# Python - Index Error: string index out of range

Tags: python

I'm trying to replicate [Adam Calhoun's experiment](https://medium.com/@neuroecology/punctuation-in-novels-8f316d542ec4#.g6r8i5l3y) of reducing classic novels to punctuation and present it in posters.

Using [his code](https://github.com/adamjcalhoun/punctuation/), I was able to get to the punctuation stage, but, when I tried to transform it in a poster, I got the "IndexError: string index out of range" error message in the "symb = txt[jj + ii * symbolsPerLine]" line.

```
for ii in range(linesOfText):
    for jj in range(symbolsPerLine):
        symb = txt[jj + ii * symbolsPerLine]
        if (symb == "."):
            draw.text((trim + jj * deltaW, trim + ii * deltaH - round(font2size / 4)), symb, fill=endSentenceFill,
                      font=font2)
        elif (symb == ','):
            draw.text((trim + jj * deltaW, trim + ii * deltaH - round(font2size / 4)), symb, fill=transitionFill,
                      font=font2)
        elif (symb == '!') or (symb == '?'):
            draw.text((trim + jj * deltaW, trim + ii * deltaH), symb, fill=endSentenceFill, font=font2)
        elif (symb == '"') or (symb == '\'') or (symb == '(') or (symb == ')') or (symb == '[') or (symb == ']'):
            draw.text((trim + jj * deltaW, trim + ii * deltaH), symb, fill=parentheticalFill, font=font2)
        elif (symb == ';') or (symb == '-') or (symb == ':'):
            draw.text((trim + jj * deltaW, trim + ii * deltaH), symb, fill=transitionFill, font=font2)
        else:
            draw.text((trim + jj * deltaW, trim + ii * deltaH), symb, fill="green", font=font2)
```

What's the problem with the code?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing values for say, `symbolsPerLine` or `linesOfText`, since this is a range issue..I'm not familiar with the code embedded in the github source you're referencing. However, the problem in general sounds interesting, please elaborate!

Comment: We can't answer without knowing what `txt` is. Is it a list of lines? Why multiply by symbolsPerLine? Would `txt[ii][jj]` make more sense?

Comment: I have edited the original code to work directly with the punctuation-version of a novel. Here is what `txt` stands for: 

`file = open("grandeC_pont.txt", "r")
txt = file.read()
file.close()`

Comment: The entire code is in https://github.com/adamjcalhoun/punctuation/blob/master/punctuation.py. I've tried to run it without the changes I've made and the same problem appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
symb = punct[jj + ii*symbolsPerLine]
```

Comment: In this example I have edited the code to read directly a punctuation-only version of a novel. But when I've tried to run the original code (with the `punct`instead of `txt`), the same problem appeared.

Comment: then you need to take a look at how you've changed the `getPunctuation` function and you need to ensure your input file has  70 characters per row and 70 rows (assuming you're using those defaults)

Comment: I was able to fixed. When editing the code, I deleted inadvertently a function responsible for this counting. Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this

```
for ii in range(len(linesOfText)):
    for jj in range(len(symbolsPerLine)):
```

Lets say txt is 2 long but if  ii + jj * symbolsPerLine is 3 it will return index out of range

```
symb = txt[jj + ii * symbolsPerLine]
```